# Losing speech marks on page refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I have built a category navigation system using php and mysql.

```
$query = "SELECT category_name, category_desc FROM categories";
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
or die (mysql_error($dbc));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$catname = $row["category_name"];
$catdesc = $row["category_desc"];

echo "<li><a href='getsubs.php?category=$catname'>$catname<br /><span>$catdesc</span></a></li>";
```

This code provides me with a list of categories from my database.

When these categories are clicked and the getsubs.php file is requested:

```
$category= $_GET['category'];

$query = "SELECT subcategory_name FROM subcategories WHERE subcategory_parent = '$category'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
or die (mysql_error($dbc));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$subcatname = $row["subcategory_name"];

echo "<li><a href='getsubsubs.php?category=$subcatname'>$subcatname</a></li>";

$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']);

}
```

the text on the rest of the page (which is not database driven) loses any speech marks/quotation marks (") which were present at the base level. Does any one have any idea why this might be?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: Before and after:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: What's a "speech mark"? A quote (")? As well, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks... why are you escaping the category value inside your loop, AFTER the query has been executed?

Comment: yeah a quote (have always called them speech marks).

Comment: @Marc B Still learning... should mysql_real_escape_string come directly after $category= $_GET['category']; ? I found the documentation on it a little confusing.

Comment: yes. or even just `$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category'])`. The whole point of the escape is to prevent user-provided data from breaking your query. It has to be done BEFORE the data reaches the database. See http://bobby-tables.com for more details

Comment: Marc is very right in pointing out your SQL injection vulnerability. I can't see how it would affect just the quotes on the rest of the page that doesn't come from the database, though. Can you give us an example of what some of the affected text looks like in the page **source** before and after the refresh, so we can look at this aspect of the problem in more detail?

Comment: @Marc B Thanks, that makes it much easier to make sense of :0)

Comment: @Matt Gibson Updated to show before and after. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you actually paste the source of the samples as text? I can't even see those images.

Comment: @Richard: that's a character set mismatch issue. Something like the database is providing UTF-8 data, and your page is being rendered as ISO-8859, or vice-versa

Comment: @Marc B Weird thing is its working fine at the base level which contains data from the same database. I will check to see if I can find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Depends how it's going into the database. You need to make sure that you're collecting, storing, retrieving and displaying data in a consistent character set, and rendering your page with the correct character set displayed. Sounds likely to me that you've got two different encodings of quotation marks stored in your database.

Comment: @Matt Gibson I think your probably right. I will have to dig around a bit and see whats what.. Thanks so much for your input I'll let you know what I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was nothing to do with my character encoding which upon checking were all correct. The problem was that I had been using a different type of quotation mark which I still cannot find on my keyboard.

Quote type 1 = “ (this one was causing the problem)
Quote type 2 = " (this can be found above the right shift key on a mac)

The text had been copied and pasted from another file which contained these weird quotation marks.
If anyone knows where this alternative mark came from it would be useful to know for the future.

Many thanks for all your input guys.

Comment: Quote type two is a "typewriter" quote; type one is a "real" quotation mark, an open "curly" quote. If you want to type one on your Mac, from memory, you use the square bracket keys, with Alt+[ and Shift+Alt+[. For single quotes, use the same trick with the ] key. For more information than you could possibly need, see [Wikipedia's entry on Quotation Mark Glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs). There's no reason why the “curly” quotes should cause a problem if you're using UTF8 -- as you can see, Stack Overflow happily copes with them, for example.

Comment: @Matt Gibson Thanks Matt! Everything is set to UTF8 yet I still can't get the real quotation mark to work. All column in all tables are set to utf8_unicode_ci and then I have my meta as follows: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 1):

Those `?` often show up because of unicode encoding issues. Your tables `subcategories` and `categories` probably have different collations. One is probably one of the unicode varieties and the other has fewer options. Try this for a quick fix:

```
-- in the top query:
SELECT 
    category_name COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci, 
    category_desc COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
FROM categories

-- in the bottom query
SELECT subcategory_name COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci 
   FROM subcategories WHERE subcategory_parent = '$category'"
```

A more correct approach would be to change both tables to use the same collation and/or adjust the encoding output with a `<meta>` tag. (something like `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />` would probably do it)

(As an aside, I more or less have to remark that you should be using `mysql_real_escape_string` around your DB inputs)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I would rather get it right first time than use any quick fixes but to know I can do that is great. Thanks. I will look at changing the collation of both tables :0)

Comment: @richard I would also read Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), if you haven't come across it yet.

Comment: @Matt Gibson Brilliant. I came across it a couple of weeks ago and hadn't got round to reading it yet Haha. That'll teach me!